# Writing a C++20 range to standard output

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++20

I can take several `int`s from a `vector` putting them to standard output with an iterator:

```
std::vector<int> v{0,1,2,3,4,5};
std::copy_n(v.begin(),
    3,
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ":"));
```

I can use the new C++20 ranges to take several `int`s from a `vector` putting them to standard output with `|` operator in a `for` loop, one value at a time using `<<`.

```
for(int n : std::views::all(v)
    | std::views::take(3))
{
    std::cout << n << '/';
}
```

How can I put the results of `std::views::all(v) | std::views::take(3)` to standard output w/o explicitly looping through values?

Something like:

```
std::views::all(v)
    | std::views::take(4)
    | std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ");
```

or

```
std::cout << (std::views::all(v)
    | std::views::take(4));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The specific thing you're looking for is using the new ranges algorithms:

```cpp
std::ranges::copy(v | std::views::take(4),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

You don't need to use `views::all` directly, the above is sufficient.

You can also use fmtlib, either directly:

```cpp
// with <fmt/ranges.h>
// this prints {0, 1, 2, 3}
fmt::print("{}\n", v | std::views::take(4));
```

or using `fmt::join` to get more control (this lets you apply a format string to each element in addition to specifying the delimiter):

```cpp
// this prints [00:01:02:03]
fmt::print("[{:02x}]\n", fmt::join(v | std::views::take(4), ":"));
```

Comment: What compiler are you running with for this? This is not supported on N compilers. Downvoting this , you need to provide version/environment information when posting.

Comment: @user3613174 Um, okay. That is not actually a rule. It would be an especially tedious one for situations like this - which are simply valid for all C++20 conforming compilers. That's kind of the point of portability.